# How to keep NSIS install window open?

Tags: nsis, modern-ui

When I press "Install" there is a small window showing the files that are being copied and other operations such as registering dlls, etc..
I would like to keep that window open when it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE
!include MUI2.nsh
...
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

Comment: I have those. The install window stays open but the little window showing what the installer is doing is closed right after it is done. I'm using now dumplog. https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-340310.html

Comment: Are you sure you have MUI_FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE?

Comment: You are right! The script had !define FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE without the MUI. Thanks!